# Gloabally insertion >> and extraction << operator for Dice class

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

What does that mean? globally like:

what I did was:

```
class Dice{
int a; //data member
//constructors
 friend ostream & operator << (ostream &out, const Dice &D);
 friend istream & operator >> (istream &in,  Dice &D);
}
ostream & operator << (ostream &out, const Dice &D)
{
    out << D.a << endl;
    return out;
}
istream & operator >> (istream &in,  Dice &D)
{
    cout << "Enter a: ";
    in >> D.a;
    return in;
}
```

but this is not global, right? how am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Unless you have wrapped all this in a namespace you don't show (and that your real code have the terminating `;` at the end of the class definition) then those operator function will be declared and defined in the global namespace.

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't print prompts in your input operator `>>`. What happens if you try to read from a file instead? Which can happen if the user uses pipes or input redirection. And don't add a newline in the output operator `<<`, it's better done when the operator is used.